# Как добавить reply и inline клавиатуру в одном сообщении

Tags: python, aiogram, клавиатура, бот

Всех приветствую.
Нужно добавить inline и reply клавиатуру сразу после /start
Не могу понять как это можно сделать, так как в сообщение можно добавить или то или то
Можно ли вообще так сделать и как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

В одном никак, только двумя разными.

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(message: types.Message):
    markup_reply = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True).add("1", "2")
    markup_inline = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup().add(
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='1', callback_data='1'),
        types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='2', callback_data='2'))

    await message.answer("reply", reply_markup=markup_reply)
    await message.answer("inline", reply_markup=markup_inline)
```